# Heroku Error Database when i make the deployment

Tags: heroku

i have a app, it's make with express and SQL, in localahost the app works perfectly, but when i make the deployment, the app works, but only part of the app.
The app has a Database makes with SQL, with two tables.

App: [Database APP](https://internship-database.herokuapp.com/)

I have access to the first table (alumnos), i can see the full list, show the individual item, and edit it.

But the other table (Empresas) i can see the full list, but when i try to go to edit or show one i have an issue.

Heroku shows me "Internal server error", but in "Views Logs" in Heroku, i can see the data values from the selection, and this error.

```
2021-06-16T05:39:21.076820+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed tolookup view "empresas/mostrarempresa" in views directory "/app/views"
```

2021-06-16T05:39:21.076821+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)

2021-06-16T05:39:21.076822+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)

2021-06-16T05:39:21.076822+00:00 app[web.1]: at paginadetallesEmpresa (file:///app/controllers/paginasControllers.js:84:9)

2021-06-16T05:39:21.076823+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Comment: The link to the logs isn't working, can you just past the logs into your post?

Comment: Stackoverflow not allowed me, to upload photos, and the link is from imgur.com, is not my fault. I am sad :(

Comment: @ddaudiosolutions you should copy and paste the text of the logs, we prefer to avoid images on SO.

Comment: yes, now i log heroku in terminal, now i posted the error. thanks

Comment: I fixed migrating the database from tableplus, because the first time i used mysqldump line command. Now works perfectly